# how to build regular expressions

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm dealing with some google spreadsheet with data, some of which is in a very confused way, but regular, so i hope we can figure this out.

I've tried reg ex builders but I can't find the right one for google sheets or I misunderstand some stuff.

I would appreciate help with these sentances below:

```
 1. {"user":{"Czy faktura?":"Y","Nazwa firmy":"Name of the company ","NIP":"113 234 20 57"}}
 2. {"user":{"Czy faktura?":"Y","Nazwa firmy":"The longer name of the company","NIP":"2352225961"}}
 3. {"user":{"Czy faktura?":"N","Nazwa firmy":"","NIP":""}}
```

The point is to extract: (using arrayformula in google sheets)

1. Y or N
2. Name of the company
3. NIP number

**Problems**:

The name of the company has different lengths, and the NIP number is sometimes with white-spaces.

Do you guys have any idea how can I properly use it?

I know it's the REGEXEXTRACT formula of course :)

Just have a problem on how to formulate the regular expression..

Comment: Use a JSON parser, not regex, to parse JSON.

Comment: This is not a constructive comment. There is no JSON parser available in Google Sheets as a formula, and to create even a simple one in the Script editor is an order of magnitude more difficult than just using an (admittedly imperfect) regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
=regexreplace(B1, "(^.*Nazwa firmy"":"")(.*)("",""NIP.*$)", "$2")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works well with the company name. But how about the NIP number? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the support was fantastic :)

- After all, a simple "Y|N" solves the first problem
- I used @ttarchala's solution for the company name as it seems to work for some reason - i don't know why or how :)
  "(^.*Nazwa firmy"":"")(.*)("",""NIP.*$)", "$2"
- and the NIP is isolated by this one: "NIP\"":\""(.+)\"""),"-|\s","" and later trimmed of off the "-" minus and whitespaces signs.

cheers